# User input multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to allow a user to define multiple columns from which to pull data. These columns are not adjacent, i.e. there is data in columns "A", "D", "H", "P". This is just an example, the relevant columns will be different for every user. Using something like this:

```
dim data_col as range
dim data_col_1 as integer

set data_col = application.inputbox("Select your columns", Type:= 8 )

data_col_1 = data_col.column
```

Only returns the first (left-most) column index in the range. I need a way to separate this input into multiple column indexes, either into a number of different variables or an array.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below, it will loop through all of your `Areas`, and per each Area will loop though all columns, and will input their numbers in `data_col_Arr` array.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RangetoColumns()

Dim data_col As Range
Dim data_col_Arr() As Long
Dim Area As Range
Dim Col As Range
Dim i As Long

Set data_col = Application.InputBox("Select your columns", Type:=8)

ReDim data_col_Arr(1 To 1000)  ' init to large size >> will optimize at the end
i = 1
Dim MsgStr  As String
For Each Area In data_col.Areas
    For Each Col In Area.Columns
        data_col_Arr(i) = Col.Column
        MsgStr = MsgStr & data_col_Arr(i) & vbCr ' <-- for Debug Only
        i = i + 1
    Next Col
Next Area

ReDim Preserve data_col_Arr(1 To i - 1) 'Redim array size to number of columns populated
MsgBox MsgStr ' <-- for Debug Only

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for.